# How to add an accordion in djnago admin in the change_list.html template?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-admin

I want to change the default table in the django admin, which is displayed in the template change_list.html. While retaining all the functionality that django provides.

The idea is to make the table in the form of an accordion, where there will be a button "Collapse" and "Expand". In the case of clicking the button "Expand" will expand the column with the associated record and all its data

Can you tell me how to implement such functionality, I will be glad to receive any suggestions?

In simpler words, how to add the action "view_data" and when you click "Open" button the accordion will open and show all the data related to the record


[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmP27.png)